# incorrect syntax near '=' error

Tags: sql, select

I just want to retrieve the image path from my db where im providing the table name at runtime but and id too problem heres arise is that its giving me error of incorrect syntax near '='

here is my query

```
string query = "select strImage from " + tableName + "where intID ="+Id;
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add extra space before the `WHERE` clause,

```
string query = "SELECT strImage FROM " + tableName + " WHERE intID ="+Id;
                                                   -- ^ HERE
```

Let's say the value of the variable `tableName` is `Hello`, when it is concatenated, the query will looked like this,

```
SELECT strImage FROM HelloWHERE intID =0
                      --  ^ lacking space here
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope your query is right. There is a bit sytax problem.Try this

```
string query = "select strImage from " + tableName + " where intID ="+Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = String.Format("SELECT strImage FROM {0} WHERE intID = {2}", tableName, Id);
```

Concatenation of string results in creating multiple objects

Comment: this is fine if the OP is using `.net`